# simple progressbar

Tags: python, pyqt, progress-bar

As mentioned in the tittle I want to make simple progress bar. I have UI and button, that calculates some math exercise and I want to make progress bar for it. Simple just 0 to 100 from starting clicking and stopping while finishing process. I show you my code and can anyone show me how progress bar will be implemented?

```
import ui
import sys

class example (Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self,window):
        self.setupUi(window)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.exmath)

    def exmath (self):
        a2 = int (self.lineEdit_10.text())
        b2 = int (self.lineEdit_12.text())
        c2 = int (self.lineEdit_11.text())

        d2 = a2 - b2 
        e2 = d2 % c2

        self.label_32.setText(str(d2))
        self.label_31.setText(str(e2))
        if ( a2 % c2 == b2 % c2 and e2 == 0 ):
            self.label_28.setText("Right")
            self.label_28.setStyleSheet("background-color: green; color: white") 
        else:
            self.label_28.setText("Wrong")
            self.label_28.setStyleSheet("background-color: red; color: white") 

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()

ui = example (MainWindow)
MainWindow.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: "0 to 100 from starting clicking and stopping while finishing process" -> what process? Do you mean the calculation in `exmath`? Because that function would take no more than a millisecond, I don't think a progressbar would be that useful in such a case.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to implement a progress bar would be to have certain defined "steps" in your calculation, such as a loop with a known number of loops or just a sequence of calculation steps.

With that, you can implement a progressbar either by a dialog or in the progress bar. Since the statusbar implementation is a bit easier (no linking of dialog-window and calculation required), I've created a small example based on your code.

Here, I simulated the calculation with articifical delays in a while loop, while iterating the progressbar up to 100%.

[image]

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore

class ExampleProgressBar(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # create lineedit and button
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.line_edit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit('1')
        layout.addWidget(self.line_edit)
        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Calculate")
        layout.addWidget(self.button)
        widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        widget.setLayout(layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.example_math)
        # create progressbar in statusbar
        self.progress = QtWidgets.QProgressBar(self)
        self.statusBar().addPermanentWidget(self.progress)
        self.statusBar().showMessage('Ready')
        self.show()

    def example_math(self):
        self.statusBar().showMessage('Calculating...')
        self.button.setEnabled(False)
        self.button.setText('Calculating...')
        current_value = int(self.line_edit.text())
        self.completed = 10
        while self.completed < 100:  # loop until completion reaches 100 (%)
            self.artificial_delay(500)
            self.completed += 10
            self.line_edit.setText(f'{current_value + current_value}')
            current_value += current_value
            self.progress.setValue(self.completed)
        self.statusBar().showMessage('Ready')
        self.button.setEnabled(True)
        self.button.setText('Calculate')

    def artificial_delay(self, time):
        loop = QtCore.QEventLoop()
        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(time, loop.quit)
        loop.exec_()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    ui = ExampleProgressBar()
    app.exec_()
```